# How to debug and fix error [fcgid:warn] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended , get overlap result error, [core:error] End of script output before headers

Tags: 8, acquia-dev-desktop

I’m using :

- Drupal 8 on Acquia DevDesktop version 2 with php 7.0.15.
- php_mode is set to FAST CGI (mod_fcgid).
- Info from the phpinfo() Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j mod_fcgid/2.3.9

The problem is I’m getting 500 internal errors very frequently.

In the apache log this is displayed for each 500 error log as follows

```
[Thu Nov 09 09:24:36.140248 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 17112:tid 1268] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : [client 127.0.0.1:56192] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error, referer: http://inzicht5.dd:8083/

[Thu Nov 09 09:24:36.140750 2017] [core:error] [pid 17112:tid 1268] [client 127.0.0.1:56192] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: http://inzicht5.dd:8083/
```

Therefore I added into php.ini

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

And I added in php.ini

```
error_log = C:\php_errors.log
```

Activated error.log in php.ini. Checked by  phpinfo(). But still no php error is shown up. Yes, I restarted the server

I already installed MS distribution C++ 2015 version 14.024215

But still I do not get more information. Also I googled a lot of sites for this error but none of them are giving me directions.

How to get more debug information about this error?
How to solve it?

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug in dev desktop: https://forums.acquia.com/acquia-products-and-services/dev-desktop/internal-server-error

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in the newest Varbase release. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2912709

Comment: Yes, this works

Comment: Sorry mistake, it is not working. I tested with drupal only site, It is not related to varbase